# Zookeeper doesn't start correctly on Centos7

Tags: centos, hdfs, apache-zookeeper, centos7

I have configured zookeeper on Centos 7.
when I try to see the status it throws the next:

```
[ikerlan@server1 ~]$ /opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/zkServer.sh status

 ZooKeeper JMX enabled by default
    Using config: /opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
    Error contacting service. It is probably not running.
```

If I run zkServer.sh start-foreground

```
 -10-06 10:26:36,550 [myid:1] - WARN  [WorkerSender[myid=1]:QuorumCnxManager@400] - Cannot open channel to 2 at election address /172.16.8.242:3888
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No existe ninguna ruta hasta el `host'
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
```

This is my ~/.bashrc:

```
###JAVA CONFIGURATION###
 JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_74/jre/
 export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

###HADOOP CONFIGURATION###
 HADOOP_PREFIX=hadoop/
 export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin:$HADOOP_PREFIX/sbin
#finHadoop

###ZOOKEEPER###
 export PATH=$PATH:/opt/zookeeper-3.4.9/bin
#finZookeper
```

zoo.cfg:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/opt/ZooData
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2

server.1=172.16.8.241:2888:3888
server.2=172.16.8.242:2888:3888
server.3=172.16.8.243:2888:3888
```

/opt/ZooData/myid is configured

```
[ikerlan@server1 ~]$ sudo lsof -P -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN  | grep 2181
java    14568 ikerlan   25u  IPv6  53119      0t0  TCP *:2181 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION:

I have disabled the firewall in all the cluster nodes and it works fine.

```
sudo systemctl stop firewalld
```

Answer (score 0):

A process already running and bound to port 2181 for sure. 
Check below command:

```
$ telnet <zookeeper-server-ip> 2181  # Just to know if some process is listening on port 2181
```

Then you may check which process is is listening on 2181 by issuing the below command:

```
 $lsof -P -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN  | grep 2181
```

Comment: On port 2181 is java listenning, is it a problem? You can see the output when on the description. Java process starts listenning on port 2181, when I start zkServer.sh